# Pass arguments with space in GDB?

Tags: command-line, gdb

I am trying to pass argument "print 100" into gdb using command

```
(gdb) run "print 100"
```

However, but gdb interprets it as 2 commands "\"print" and 100\". I have also tried escaping the spaces print\ 100 but that is not working either.

I am using macOS.
Thanks.

Comment: I am using MacOS

Comment: Edit necesary information into the question.

Comment: Have you tried using single quote?

Comment: yes, it is then treated as "'print"

Comment: This works fine with either single or double quotes on Linux. I suspect it also works fine on MacOS, but you either are mis-interpreting what you see, or have something in your `~/.bashrc` that interferes.

Comment: IIRC on recent versions of MacOS, gdb can't launch the inferior via the shell, so it does its own primitive argument splitting.